# Running multiple Simulations of a Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a model that simulates a trajectory around Earth based on its impact angle, 'i'. For each impact angle, the 'runTime' must increase to generate a larger path of the trajectory. The goal is to stop the simulation when the object gets below a certain altitude, in this case 100000. This code currently works, but using such a large run time with a small step takes a lot of time. Are there any tricks to optimizing this process or at the very least, a cleaner method?

```
%Example
mdl = 'myModel';
load_system(mdl);
i = [-30 -29];
for a = 1:length(i)
    Input1 = i(a);

    for b = 7000:10:12000
        runTime = b;
        % Simulate model
        sim(mdl);
        load('myOutput.mat')
        if myOutput(1,1) <= 100000
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you seen `parsim`? https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/parsim.html

Comment: Personally I'd use the "Stop Simulation" block inside simulink to stop the model rather than trying to detect the stop event externally. Just set the Stop Time to 'inf' and use some comparison blocks to detect your <=100000 event.